# when i want to edit a text, my button goes up because its constraint to the bottom how can i prevent that?

Tags: android

I don't want the text to come up with the keyboard. is there a code so it stays at the bottom. i tried to constraint in to the top but then there is some space between my buttons and the bottom of my screen and i dont want that i want it at the bottom against the bottom line of the screen

[before i click my editview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnGam.png)

[after i clicked my editview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOBDK.png)

> here is my Layoutcode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductInfo">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="219dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Location"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="191dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Datum"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/locatieTbl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eanInputTxt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Savebtn"
        android:text="Opslaan"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancelBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Cancellbtn"
        android:text="Annulleer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/saveBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idEanTxt"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="IdOrEan"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Location"
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Geen Vaknummer"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Quantity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Quantity"
        android:layout_width="191dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Aantal"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTxt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eanInputTxt"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Ean"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="0000030098572"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="193dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTxt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:onClick="SearchEan"
        android:text="Zoeken"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/eanInputTxt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Scanner" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Scanner"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:onClick="scanner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Search"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eanInputTxt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="backBtn"
        android:text="Terug"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: Show us your layout code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i have added my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AdjustPan :** The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

**AdjustNothing :** The window does not change at all here and the keyboard appears on top of it.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

You can try one of them. Add your manifest file.

Comment: i tried that and it doesn't work still same problem

Comment: I tried your code. It works fine. You should add to your activity in manifest?